# SocketChannel: Single or multi , which is better?

Tags: java, networking, nio

**SocketChannel** is thread safe, so only one channel is need for communication between client and server. the channel served for read/write operations simultaneously
  But, if we using multi channels (*more than one connections between the same client and server*), will the io performance be improved ??? 
  If can, why??????
  any answer is welcome.

Suppose a cache client, which poll data from remote server.

```
public class Client(){
    public Object getThroungOneChannel(Object key){
       getTheUniqueChannel().write(request);
       waitForResponse();
    }

    public Object getWithMultiChannel(Object key){
       getChannelFromAPool().write(request)
       waitForResponse();
    }
}
```

which way will have better io performance.

Comment: you mean multiple channel for the same connection? how could you get ttwo different channels for the same connection?

Comment: not the same connection, but using multi connections between same client and server

Comment: +1 this question doesent deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a single connection between a  client and server is the best way to go. I can't imagine how multiple connections to transfer same data between same client and server could help. With a proper implementation of command-pattern, you could optimize the usage of the channel to max, in fact that's the whole advantage of NIO. For e.g., suppose even if you have a thread writing to a channel blocked producing data, you could have another thread writing some other data to the same channel, but you have to code smartly to extract the best out of NIO.

And for your given example, I believe, in trivial cases the `getThroungOneChannel()` will outperform `getWithMultiChannel()`

Comment: i have update the question. the situation is i want the client to perform sending request simultaneously. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually using of several TCP connections don't increase performance.

In case of "long fat pipe network", a single TCP connection is not able to use all available bandwidth. In that case several TCP connections may increase performance.

Google "long fat pipe" for getting more information.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs of the SocketChannel class

"Socket channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. They support concurrent reading and writing, though at most one thread may be reading and at most one thread may be writing at any given time. The connect and finishConnect methods are mutually synchronized against each other, and an attempt to initiate a read or write operation while an invocation of one of these methods is in progress will block until that invocation is complete."

So it appears that the reads/writes through multiple threads are serialized. So one channel has only a limited throughput. But if you are talking about having multiple channels - assuming all of them are connected to different sockets (ports) on the client/server, it should have more IO performance. A test would be able to prove this out and here are some samples of how to use the Socket and SocketChannel classes for this test. http://www.exampledepot.com/taxonomy/term/196

HTH, K

Comment: I have read the doc already. It only indicates that 'connect' and 'finishConnect' is mutually synchronized. Does not that mean other operations like read/wirte can execute concurrently!

Comment: Which i confused is that the physical network device may also server io request in a serialized way. So multi connections may have no sense

Comment: -1. The network is the rate-determining step, not the CPU or threading.

Answer (score 0):

There can be times when multiple connections outperform single connections, and that's usually when the ISP has traffic shaping, or when the remote system is configured to only deliver a certain amount of bandwidth per connection.